# how do i create a Map with a key that refers to a set

Tags: java, collections, set

I want to sort products into sets associated with their category as a key. Im not sure how to do this. It seems my code keeps added all the products to the same set.

the code i have so far:

// to create the new map

```
public class ProductList implements ProductListInterface {
static Collection<Product> productList = new TreeSet<Product>(); 
private Map<String, Set<Product>> productCategory = new HashMap<>();


public void filter(){

     for (Product item: productList){
         String key = item.getCategory();
     if (productCategory.containsKey(key)){
       Set<Product> set =  productCategory.get(key);
       set.add(item);
       productCategory.put(key, set);


       }else{
     Set<Product> productSet = new HashSet<Product>();
     productSet.add(item);
     productCategory.put(key, productSet);

       }


     }


 }
```

// and then to retrieve the set with the category key

```
public Collection<Product> getFilter(String category){
     return productCategory.get(category);

 }
```

Comment: This code works. The problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
public void filter(){

     for (Product item: productList){
         String key = item.getCategory();

         if(productCategory.get(key) == null){
            Set<Product> productSet = new HashSet<Product>();
            productCategory.put(key, productSet);
         }

         Set<Product> set =  productCategory.get(key);
         set.add(item);
         productCategory.put(key, set);
     }

}
```

It should work, if not, try to debug the `key`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, although I ran your code and it was fine too. Maybe the problem is somewhere else.

```
Collection<Product> productList = . . .
Map<String,Set<Product>> map =
        productList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getCategory,
                Collectors.toSet()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Frederico that your code works, but you don't need to repeat yourself, and you don't need to put the set back into the map.

```
for (Product item : productList) {
    String key = item.getCategory();
    Set<Product> set = productCategory.get(key);
    if (set == null) {
        set = new HashSet<>();
        productCategory.put(key, set);
    }
    set.add(item);
}
```

Since that is a **very** common pattern, you can even compress the code a bit.

```
for (Product item : productList) {
    String key = item.getCategory();
    Set<Product> set = productCategory.get(key);
    if (set == null)
        productCategory.put(key, set = new HashSet<>());
    set.add(item);
}
```